# Cannot find package "api/handlers"

Tags: go

Ok so this question has been asked before and I believe I have looked through all of them to and tested the answers but I will explain how each one doesn't match my case. I might have missed the answer in one of those but I read each one and attempted to see if it could fit my case

[How to import local packages in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480623/how-to-import-local-packages-in-go) I believe my imports follow the structure of the answer

[Go build: "Cannot find package" (even though GOPATH is set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214029/go-build-cannot-find-package-even-though-gopath-is-set) I'm not sure if this one is fully pertinent but I don't think it's the same error.

[Golang - Why can't I import local package in GOPATH/src/project but can in home directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815455/golang-why-cant-i-import-local-package-in-gopath-src-project-but-can-in-home) My import path isn't relative so this question isn't pertinent.

My error is simple:

```
cannot find package "api/handlers" in any of: 
C:\Go\src\api\handlers (from $GOROOT) 
C:\Projects\Go\src\api\handlers (from $GOPATH)`
```

My project structure is as follows:

```
src
|
 --api
   |
    -- index.go
    -- repo.go
   |
   github.com
   |
   main.go
```

Environment variables:

```
$GOPATH : C:\Projects\Go
$GOROOT : C:\Go\
```

index and repo.go both have the same package name, imports, and just an empty function:

```
package handlers

import (
    "net/http"
)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
}
```

My main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "api/handlers"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/api/index", handlers.indexHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/api/repo", handlers.repoHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServer("localhost:8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: There is no folder `handlers` in `api`.

Comment: @tkausl Yes but from what I've read in the previous answers it seems you end with the package name. If I try to just do `api` it removes the error on the import and puts an error on the main that says `cannot refer to unexported name handlers.indexHandler`

Comment: I understand the downvotes due to the amount of "duplicates" but I believe that Topo's answer adds some better explanation, especially for the part about the capitalization because I missed that in many tutorials. Things like that are easy to overlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that `import api/handlers` is looking for the folder `handlers` in the folder `api`, and then looking in the contents for the package name. Add a `handlers` folder inside `api` and move `index.go` and `repo.go` into that folder. Or just change the package name to `api` in those files and just do `import api`.

About your comment:

> cannot refer to unexported name handlers.indexHandler

In order for you to be able to use function `indexHandler` from your main package, you should rename it to `IndexHandler`. In go, for things to be able to be accessed by other packages, the name needs to start with a capital letter.

Comment: So the combination of adding the other folder (or just importing api) and then capitalizing the function (which I must have missed completely in the docs) worked.

When I read the other answers, I assumed that what you ended the import with was the name of the package not the name of the folder.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy Good. the part about capitalizing the letters for exported functions or variables, because it's easy to miss when passing a struct to another package to do something with it, it won't be able to see the fields that are not exported (Start with a capital letter).